# AWS Lambda - Error [CredentialsError]: Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

We're using Lambda functions and only for some executions, do we get this error.

```
Error [CredentialsError]: Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:497:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:393:35)
    at Object.readFileSync (/var/task/back/requests/router.js:2:965376)
    at constructor.o [as parseFile] (/var/task/back/requests/router.js:2:950732)
    at constructor.loadFrom (/var/task/back/requests/router.js:2:951161)
    at Object.getProfilesFromSharedConfig (/var/task/back/requests/router.js:2:978785)
    at constructor.load (/var/task/back/requests/router.js:2:798037)
    at constructor.coalesceRefresh (/var/task/back/requests/router.js:2:783742)
    at constructor.refresh (/var/task/back/requests/router.js:2:798989)
    at constructor.get (/var/task/back/requests/router.js:2:783568) {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'CredentialsError',
  path: '/home/sbx_user1051/.aws/credentials',
  time: 2022-05-13T23:23:18.700Z,
  originalError: {
    message: 'Could not load credentials from constructor',
    errno: -2,
    syscall: 'open',
    code: 'CredentialsError',
    path: '/home/sbx_user1051/.aws/credentials',
    time: 2022-05-13T23:23:18.700Z,
    originalError: {
      errno: -2,
      syscall: 'open',
      code: 'ENOENT',
      path: '/home/sbx_user1051/.aws/credentials',
      message: "ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/sbx_user1051/.aws/credentials'"
    }
  }
}
```

I suspect that this is related to the lambda being triggered by an SQS event, not by the API?

I don't mind following the advice of any of the other answers on the subject, but it is really bugging me that only a few lambda functions are facing this issue and not all functions in the application.

Comment: Lambda functions get their credentials seamlessly if you correctly configure the function with an appropriate IAM role.

Comment: Using serverless, that should be done by default.

Comment: Does this same Lambda function work correctly sometimes but fail with CredentialsError at other times? I haven't seen an issue with a correctly-configured Lambda function failing to load role-based credentials. What specific code does this failure relate to?

Comment: This specific function is triggered by an SQS event, and it calls dynamo db.
Other functions call the same dynamo db interface but are triggered by API GATEWAY and they all work with no issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

False alarm.

I discovered having hard-coded credentials in one of the files calling aws-sdk, turns out it has nothing to do with dynamodab.

[image]